# Save file with Kotlin Coroutines in Android shows inappropiate blocking method call

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I created a function for saving an image to the internal files directory. I execute this function in the lifecycleScope provided by Android like following:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        saveImage(id, proxyEntity)
    }
}
```

This is my function where I want to save the image.

```kotlin
    private suspend fun saveImage(
            id: Long,
            proxyEntity: ProxyEntity,
        ) {
            val entitiesDirectory = File(filesDir, "local/entities")
            if (false == entitiesDirectory.isDirectory) {
                entitiesDirectory.mkdirs()
            }
            if (null != selectedImage) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val entityFile = File(entitiesDirectory, "$id")
                    val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(entityFile)
                    //selectedImage is of type Bitmap
                    fileOutputStream.write(ImageUtil.convertBitmapToByteArray(selectedImage!!))
                    fileOutputStream.close()
                    proxyEntity.imagePath = "local/entities/${id}"
                }
            }
        }
```

The code itself is working, but my question is, why Android-Studio still shows me "Inappropriate blocking method call" and if I am doing anything wrong.

**EDIT:**
The message is appearing on `FileOutputStream(entityFile)` and the `write` and `close` function.

Comment: You are calling File(filesDir, "local/entities") that is too an I/O operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE: After reading `Tenfour04`'s comment

At first I was hesitant, because in theory, `suspend` doesn't imply anything about the context. But like most things in life, after thinking more about it (and sleeping), I think it makes sense in a practical way to make some *controlled* and *consistent* choices. Among them, to ensure:

1. That you can replace the Dispatcher in a Unit Test (this means: don't hardcode, instead, inject it so you can replace it).

E.g.:
instead of:

```
...launch(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }
```

Do:

```
class XYZ(private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default) { 
 

suspend fun xyz() = withContext(defaultDispatcher) { ... }
```

You get the idea.

2. Suspend functions *should be safe to call from main thread*

This is an interesting choice but I understand why. And I will start doing this in all my code where I can.
Source: [Suspend functions should be safe to call from the main thread](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#main-safe).

I suggest you read the [Coroutines Best Practices](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices) recently updated/published by Google. We may all have our disagreements and use a different patterns here and there, but overall, I'd do what Google suggests; in the end, it's their platform and the closer you are to their code, the easier will be to deal with the incessant changes and deprecation that happen in modern development these days.

#### UPDATE: I haven't had coffee.

Ok, after re-reading your code, I noticed you do specify the Coroutine Context.

That being said, I'd make the context assignment the way I did it (in the viewmodel launch's call).

You don't want your code to "care" which context is used on, instead let the viewmodel decide what's best.

#### Original Response

The I/O operations on the main thread are a bad idea (if not forbidden by some APIs), so you need to change the scheduler

Your code:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        saveImage(id, proxyEntity)
}
```

Is running on the Default scheduler (likely Main Thread).

Try instead to use the I/O one:

```
lifecyleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   saveImage(id, proxyEntity)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, even with the answer you wrote before your first coffee I got what you mean. It also works way better now! Thank you ^^

Comment: Glad to hear, happy coding! :)

Comment: This advice is the opposite of what I consider to be proper convention. A `suspend` function should be safe to call from any dispatcher, because it encapsulates delegation of blocking work to other dispatchers. Otherwise, it might as well be a blocking function that requires you to read its source to see what dispatcher you need to safely call it. `suspend` mean, "I'm safe to call without concern about blocking or being on the wrong thread."

Comment: @Tenfour04 I agree to some degree, but that's not the whole picture. Nowhere in the suspend contract is specified that it's safe to call from any specific dispatcher; this is up to your own architecture and domain. The only thing the suspend function guarantees is the fact that it can/will suspend the caller. Your viewmodel in this particular instance is responsible for managing that. But it's all debatable. I prefer to specify the dispatcher that I'm using in my viewmodels instead of blindly calling `launch {}` and hope that the Default dispatcher is "ok" for what I need.

Comment: I just came across this blog post from the horse's mouth, and it's probably where I originally got the idea that this is the convention. See the section titled *Suspending convention* [here](https://elizarov.medium.com/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761).

Comment: @Tenfour04 interesting, it's a valid convention but I've never seen it in practice, perhaps it's worth experimenting with it. In any case, if the OP wants to do that, then it's a matter of using the `withContext(...)` as the whole body of the function.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Conveniently, there's another Google post about this https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices and it says the same: "they should be safe to call from the main thread" so I guess you're right. :) I hope the OP sees this.